# Receive items from a XAMARIN feed

Tags: xamarin

With this command I search all the items of a url where he looks for 10 items, now I need with this command to select only the item from the fifth position,
Returning only one item, how can I do this using the command below, what changes should I make

```
private async Task<List<FeedItem>> ParseFeed(string rss)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(rss);
        var id = 0;
        return (from item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                let enclosure = item.Element("enclosure")
                where enclosure != null
                select new FeedItem
                {
                    Title = (string)item.Element("title"),
                    Description = (string)item.Element("description"),
                    Link = (string)item.Element("link"),
                    PublishDate = DateTime.Parse((string)item.Element("pubDate")).ToUniversalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
                    Category = (string)item.Element("category"),
                    Mp3Url = (string)enclosure.Attribute("url"),
                    Image = (string)enclosure.Attribute("url"),
                    Color_category =Convert.ToString(int.Parse((string)item.Element("color")), 16).PadLeft(6, '0'),
                Id = id++
                }).ToList();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Skip() and Take()

```
    return (from item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
    ...
    }).Skip(4).Take(1).ToList();
```